# CartoDB Twitter code bl.ocks non-functional with namedmap type viz

Tags: carto, popup, twitter

I'm working with the code example shown here http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/6029822
When I substitute Javi's viz for a namedmap map type viz it fails with the following error
"TypeError: r is not a constructor cartodb.js:18"
Swapping out the js include from the  dev version to the  production version
the map loads, but the info windows fails populate or get fully styled.

My Question - Does anyone see what might need to be changed in order for this code to function properly with namedmaps?
If not any help in understanding the difference between namedmap and layergroup type vizs would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you please show how you initialize the named map?

Comment: Please, could you share your entire code?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you need to do is declare your interactivity variables in your config file when you first create your named map.

Here's an example of a named map with infowindows on specific variables:
http://bl.ocks.org/ohasselblad/d1a45b8ff5e7bd90cd68

The config file is also on that page. It's based on earthquake data from [here](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/csv.php).